# Create Table with schema and data from old table

Tags: go

Im working on a script that's meant to: Set a table name based on the old table with an included suffix date time (eg. table_1_2020_01_01, create a schema for that table based on an older table's schema, then insert data into that table from the old table.

I created three MySQL statements that are meant to set the table name, create the table, and then insert data into the created table:

```
SET @TABLE_NAME = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%m_%d'), '_new_table');

SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS', @TABLE_NAME, 'LIKE old_table');
                            PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
                            EXECUTE stmt;
                            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @SQL = CONCAT('INSERT INTO', @TABLE_NAME, 'SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE id = ?');
                            PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
                            EXECUTE stmt USING @id;
                            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However, every time I run my run my func from main, I receive this error:

```
panic: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
                                                        EXECUTE stmt;
                                                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt' at line
```

I found that Set Table name as a var in golang. So my resolution was use a prepared statements and pass the var into the prepared statements.

Maybe something like:

```
stmt, err := tx.Prepare("CREATE TABLE (?) ...")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
} 
defer stmt.Close() // danger!
_, err = stmt.Exec(tableNameVariable)
```

Is there a way that I can use **_, err = db.Exec(** to run the above queries or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GORM library to interact with your database.
GORM is a SQL "builder" that also allows you to write direct queries to edit the database.

https://gorm.io/docs/

https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html

In addition, gorm supports MySQL.